# Run one or many concurrent jobs in Jenkins with different parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create a jenkins job that will run some code on various servers to validate them.

I would like to be able to specify either an individual server or give a directive such as "evens" for servers 02, 04, 06... or "odds" for servers 01, 03, 05... and have the job run for either a single or many servers.

I'm searching for the cleanest way to do this, I've tried using a scheduler job that would handle the odds and evens cases but would prefer, if possible, not to have to split the single and many server cases into different jobs. I've also looked into using a matrix job that could be configured to run under different parameter set but haven't found any documentation to fully solve my problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understood you but I will try:

I understood that you want to activate the same job many times with different parameters.

your options are :
1. using master job that will activate all other jobs with different parameters ( like you said with matrix or even simpler )
2. you can do it in pipeline rather easily with node scopes and loops for using different parameters
3. you can use jenkins-cli and activate the same job with different parameters every activation.

I hope it helped you